# How to loop over async methods without async/await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, for-loop, task-parallel-library

Without using c# async/await features, what is the best way to loop over async operations without blocking?

For instance, downloading a list of urls' HTML asynchronously within a for loop.

I keep ending up on a while loop with a TPL continuewith calling itself if there's more work.... But is there a better way?

Comment: there are some libraries that use ienumerable of iasync results like powerthreading (async await is based on this) in case you dont have net 4.5 support.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using `async`-`await`?

Comment: i'm looking to avoid async/await because its a new language feature (hadn't had a ton of production time in the community yet) and im concerned about its side effects-- memory usage, error cases, and such. i'd rather watch the community make any mistakes first and then go in on it.

Comment: plus, you can't parallel.for over an await

Comment: I found this article which also outlined a solution, as well as code for parallel async foreach http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/05/10278165.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern that you describe is not bad, but you can abstract it into a helper method. Something like `ForEachAsync` or `ConvertAllAsync`. That removes the looping from your code. This reduces the non-essential complexity to a minimum.

---

Here is an implementation of `ForEachAsync`:

```
    public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this TaskFactory factory, IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, int, Task> getProcessItemTask)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        IEnumerator<T> enumerator = items.GetEnumerator();
        int i = 0;

        Action<Task> continuationAction = null;
        continuationAction = ante =>
            {
                if (ante.IsFaulted)
                    tcs.SetException(ante.Exception);
                else if (ante.IsCanceled)
                    tcs.TrySetCanceled();
                else
                    StartNextForEachIteration(factory, tcs, getProcessItemTask, enumerator, ref i, continuationAction);
            };

        StartNextForEachIteration(factory, tcs, getProcessItemTask, enumerator, ref i, continuationAction);

        tcs.Task.ContinueWith(_ => enumerator.Dispose(), TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

        return tcs.Task;
    }
    static void StartNextForEachIteration<T>(TaskFactory factory, TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs, Func<T, int, Task> getProcessItemTask, IEnumerator<T> enumerator, ref int i, Action<Task> continuationAction)
    {
        bool moveNext;
        try
        {
            moveNext = enumerator.MoveNext();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tcs.SetException(ex);
            return;
        }

        if (!moveNext)
        {
            tcs.SetResult(null);
            return;
        }

        Task iterationTask = null;
        try
        {
            iterationTask = getProcessItemTask(enumerator.Current, i);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tcs.SetException(ex);
        }

        i++;

        if (iterationTask != null)
            iterationTask.ContinueWith(continuationAction, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, factory.Scheduler ?? TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
```

Comment: this is a really interesting idea. have you done this before?

Comment: Yeah. I have added my implementation. You can build the other primitives from this one (an async for-loop would be a foreach over Enumerable.Range(0, ...)).

Comment: Now i'll begin figuring out how to make this loop parallel -- have you done that?

Comment: That's easier than serial. If the list of URLs is kind of small you can start all tasks at one and WaitAll or WhenAll all of them. Be careful not to flood the network though. You might need some throttling.

Comment: Nm. A simple way that i did parallel on it-- split the enumerable into two batches and then run Task.WaitAll on a task for the first, and a task for the second.